# How do I programatically create an exchange 2010 mailbox using C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, exchange-server

I have been given a task to write a program to automatically create a 2010 exchange mailbox.  My research tells me to use powershell but I can't seem to find the namespace to reference and would like some sample code.  I found some code on the web but I don't know what the namespace is for PowerShell.  I think it might be System.Management.Automation but when I try to reference the namespace it does not exist in the list of dotnet.  All I have is System.Management and System.Management.Instrumentation.

Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I did it I had to download Powershell separately, not sure if this is still the case though. You can get it from [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/download-windows-powershell/).

Here is example code that will create a Mailbox:

```
SecureString password = new SecureString();
string str_password = "pass";
string username = "userr";

string liveIdconnectionUri = "http://exchange.wenatex.com/Powershell?serializationLevel=Full";

foreach (char x in str_password)
{
    password.AppendChar(x);
}

PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(username, password);

// Set the connection Info
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo((new Uri(liveIdconnectionUri)), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange",
credential);

connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Default;

// create a runspace on a remote path
// the returned instance must be of type RemoteRunspace

Runspace runspace = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);

PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
PSCommand command = new PSCommand();

command.AddCommand("Enable-Mailbox");
command.AddParameter("Identity", usercommonname);
command.AddParameter("Alias", userlogonname);
command.AddParameter("Database", "MBX_SBG_01");

powershell.Commands = command;
try
{
    // open the remote runspace
    runspace.Open();
    // associate the runspace with powershell
    powershell.Runspace = runspace;
    // invoke the powershell to obtain the results
    return = powershell.Invoke();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    // dispose the runspace and enable garbage collection
    runspace.Dispose();
    runspace = null;
    // Finally dispose the powershell and set all variables to null to free
    // up any resources.
    powershell.Dispose();
    powershell = null;
}
```

Comment: The namespace for PowerShell is: [Microsoft.PowerShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: `return = powershell.Invoke();` doesn't compile, are you missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but it might help future visitors...

w69rdy's answer did not work for me. But I got it working and blogged about it here http://pedroliska.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/running-exchange-management-shell-commands-powershell-with-c/