# How do I programatically create an Exchange 2010 mailbox using C# and an existent Active Directory user

Tags: c#, active-directory, exchange-server

Following posts like [How do I programatically create an exchange 2010 mailbox using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398056/how-do-i-programatically-create-an-exchange-2010-mailbox-using-c-sharp) and http://blog.pedroliska.com/2011/07/28/creating-an-exchange-2010-mailbox-from-a-remote-c-program/#comment-250 looks like I will be able to create a mailbox executing cmdlets on the Exchange server from a remote C# program.

My question now is how do I do to create this new mailbox using an existing Active Directory user account. I know I can do this on the Exchange UI so I'm just wondering if its possible to do it programatically through the cmdlets and how.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than calling `New-Mailbox`, call `Enable-Mailbox`. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998251.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can create new user by creating user in Active directory. I have done it for my project.You have to reference the `System.DirectoryServices.dll` assembly and the classes are in the `System.System.DirectoryServices` namespace.

the sample code to connect with Active directory is as follows :

```
        DirectoryEntry ouser = new DirectoryEntry();
        System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection userproperties;

        ouser.Path = "LDAP://CN="Username",CN="", DC="Domain",DC=Com";
        ouser.Username = UserNAme;
        ouser.Password = Password;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your workstation is in a different Site than your exchange server, you're going to need to make sure that you're making your user on the same DC that the Exchange server is using, otherwise, when you try to mail-enable your User you'll find that (s)he doesn't exist yet (as far as the Exchange Server's DC is concerned)

Anyone know a way to determine which DC an ExchangeServer is using (in C#) from remote?